# Simulate media keys in terminal

Tags: command-line, media

I have a new android phone that has a number of apps for communicating though an ssh connection. I would like to know if I can use ssh commands if I can simulate key pressed, specifically the media keys (play pause volume). I would prefer not to install additional software.

Note: I know there are apps that do this out of the box, this is simply for a better understanding.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The answer is `xdotool`, and it might already be installed on your Ubuntu system. It can simulate keypresses. See also [1].

Some commands:

- play/pause

  ```
  xdotool key XF86AudioPlay
  ```
- previous/next

  ```
  xdotool key XF86AudioPrev 
  xdotool key XF86AudioNext
  ```
- volume down/up

  ```
  xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume 
  xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume
  ```
- mute

  ```
  xdotool key XF86AudioMute
  ```

For more XF86 commands see [2].

Instead of doing the volume step by step you can also set it using alsamixer or pulseaudio (recommended). Assuming you use device 0 (you can check this with `alsamixer` or `pacmd list-sinks`) you can set the volume to for instance 80% with

- alsamixer (-c 0 specifies the sound device id)

  ```
  amixer -c 0 sset Master,0 80%
  ```
- pulseaudio (the 0 in front of the 80% is the sound device id)

  ```
  pactl set-sink-volume 0 80%
  ```

For more information about these commands see their manpages.

---

EDIT:
If you're trying to do the xdotool commands over ssh and get the following error message

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Segmentation fault
```

you need to set the DISPLAY variable:

```
export DISPLAY=':0.0'
```

After that it should work without problems

---

[1] http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml
[2] http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols

Comment: What is required for this to work over SSH?  Using these commands in a remote shell results in simulation on local machine vs remote machine.

Comment: @earthmeLon Are you sure you are running the command on the remote machine? Because for me it works fine over ssh. I needed to set the DISPLAY variable though, see my edit.

Comment: Setting the display as you suggested as resolved the problem.  Thanks :D

Comment: Note that when you are binding these to some keys in xfce4, you'll need to use the `--clearmodifiers` flag, something like this: `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioPlay`

Comment: What @cab4040 mentioned also applies to GNOME. 
If one wishes to add custom media keys on a keyboard that lacks them, one could go to the `Keyboard Shortcuts` section in settings and add a binding between a keyboard shortcut and an `xdotool key` command with `--clearmodifiers`, see above.

Comment: The `--clearmodifiers` is needed as well for `Keyboad shortcuts` in Cinnamon