# Trigger play/pause event

Tags: shortcut-keys, media

One can configure the play/pause key on his/her keyboard to start/pause music of any music player that supports this function.

I'm writing a program that should trigger these events. Currently the program calls:

```
rhythmbox-client --play
```

To start playing music. The problem with this approach is that the user for instance can use `Nuvola player`.

How can I trigger a play/pause event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tried this... Run:

```
xdotool key XF86AudioPlay
```

This just simulates the pressing of the keyboard's <kbd>Play</kbd> button - *(In my case <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)*

You may need to install Xdotool first - [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool/) might work... <sub>For the program you are making, it could be installed as dependencies.</sub>

For more commands see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/235181/178596)

Comment: [This](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xdotool) link for Xdotool might work as well...