# Add new Play/Pause shortcut key (Not Spotify)

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm new to Ubuntu and I try to configure custom Play/Pause shortcut. I have my laptop and 2 keyboards (home and work). First keyboard has Play/Pause button (Fn+F11 - this works), however second keyboard doesn't. I can change in Keyboard settings shortcut into Super+F11, and it works. But then my Fn+F11 doesn't work on first keyboard.

I tried to add new shortcut but I don't know, what to fill into Command. Here ([Trigger play/pause event](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389438/trigger-play-pause-event)) I found command `xdotool key XF86AudioPlay`. I installed xdotool but command does nothing. I also found [Play/Pause not working spotify](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090058/play-pause-not-working-spotify) but if I add listed command, shortcut works only for Spotify, not others applications.

Does anybody knows which command I should put into new custom shortcut settings?

Comment: Any different shortcut you define will work in both keyboards, there's no way around it.

Comment: I don't understand. I already added new shortcut as mentioned in link with Spotify. Now both shortcuts works, but newly added only on Spotify, not in other apps. I want 2 different shortcuts to do the same. I'm sure it is possible, I just need to know which command add.

Comment: Try `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioPlay`. Otherwise, you effectively press Super+XF86AudioPlay if you bind the command to Super+AnyKey.

Comment: @danzel amazing! It works, can you post it as answer so I can accept it? Thank you