# xdotool errors over ssh on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ssh, 20.04, xdotool

I am trying to use xdotool over ssh on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It works perfectly from within a terminal window when logged in locally, but over ssh it displays the following error from using any command:

```
$ xdotool click 1
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

Looking up this error the [fix people suggest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235126/simulate-media-keys-in-terminal/235181#235181) is exporting the DISPLAY variable before running it, but for me this only leads to a new line added to the error message:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xdotool click 1
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

Looking for "No protocol specified" errors for xdotool the [only other suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391357/run-command-on-user-display-as-root-isnt-working-as-expected) I've been able to find is also adding `export XAUTHORITY=/home/[username]/.Xauthority` to the command as well but that makes no difference for me. It's probably worth noting that I don't have an .Xauthority file in my home directory either (and creating an empty one just to see if it made a difference did not help). I'm not really familiar with X server stuff so I don't know if these things have changed since the results I'm finding where written.

I would appreciate any advice in trying to get this to work.

---

Solved: As pointed out by N0rbert I was missing the -X option when connecting over SSH. That's all I needed to include.

Comment: Did you forget `-X` in `ssh -X` ?

Comment: @N0rbert thank you! I wasn't even aware of that option. I completely glossed over it in the examples I was reading. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `ssh` with `-X` option like below:

```
ssh -X user@hostname
```

and then execute "graphical" commands as usual.

Comment: can confirm this works

Answer (score 1):

The thing is this will control the system that is connected via SSH and not the Host you want to Control.
For a example I login with the ssh -X server@192.192.192.192 and then tell xdotool to move the mouse instead of moving the mouse on the Server it moves the mouse on the client that is connected.